# Assert Current fallback trait collection contains one or more unspecified traits:

Tags: ios13, xcode11

Once our app is run on iOS13 then the log is full of wried assertions. Anybody some tips how to remove it?

```
2019-09-19 08:05:43.528382+0200 Ts-2-cz-test[56066:20590106] [Assert] Current fallback trait collection contains one or more unspecified traits: {(
    "_UITraitNameDisplayScale",
    "_UITraitNameDisplayCornerRadius",
    "_UITraitNameSemanticContext",
    "_UITraitNameUserInterfaceLevel",
    "_UITraitNamePresentationSemanticContext",
    "_UITraitNameVibrancy",
    "_UITraitNameDisplayGamut",
    "_UITraitNameDebugHighlight",
    "_UITraitNamePreferredContentSizeCategory",
    "_UITraitNameTouchLevel",
    "_UITraitNameAccessibilityContrast",
    "_UITraitNameLegibilityWeight"
)}; traitCollection: <UITraitCollection: 0x7fb4ce32ad20; HorizontalSizeClass = Compact>; currentFallbackEnvironment: <UIView: 0x7fb46c421d80; frame = (0 0; 1024 1366); autoresize = W+H; layer = <CALayer: 0x7fb46c421ef0>>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I had the same issue here because I was overriding the `traitCollection` property (which is not recommended by Apple but I didn't find any other solution in my case) and the new `traitCollection` I returned has many unspecified traits (as the error message said).

So now I return a new `traitCollection` object but I initialize it by adding `super.traitCollection`. So in my view controller I have something like:

```
public override var traitCollection: UITraitCollection {
    var newTraitCollection: [UITraitCollection] = [super.traitCollection]
    // I need to force size class on iPad
    if UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom == .pad {
        newTraitCollection += [UITraitCollection(verticalSizeClass: .regular), UITraitCollection(horizontalSizeClass: .compact)]
    }
    return UITraitCollection(traitsFrom: newTraitCollection)
}
```

Comment: @Y.Bonafons I have same problem. can you provide this solution in objective-c?

Answer (score 1):

UITraitCollection has change in iOS13. U can find out where this class has been used.

eg:
remove this method `[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassUnspecified]`

Answer (score 0):

The selected answer still give me errors. Instead you should use `@NSCopying var overrideTraitCollection: UITraitCollection? { get set }`

See more [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipresentationcontroller/1618335-overridetraitcollection)

Answer (score 0):

Objective C Code:

```
- (UITraitCollection *)traitCollection {
    NSMutableArray *newTraitCollection = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:[super traitCollection]];

    // Force size class on iPad
    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].userInterfaceIdiom == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
        [newTraitCollection addObject:[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithVerticalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassRegular]];
        [newTraitCollection addObject:[UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithHorizontalSizeClass:UIUserInterfaceSizeClassCompact]];
    }

    return [UITraitCollection traitCollectionWithTraitsFromCollections:newTraitCollection];
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).